# Msal.js 2.2 PKCE Authorization Flow Refresh Token Missing

Tags: azure-active-directory, msal.js

I am using Msal.js 2.2 (@azure/msal-browser 2.2.0) for [PKCE Authorization Code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-javascript-auth-code#how-the-tutorial-app-works), ID and Access tokens are present but no refresh token. Did I miss out anything?

```
this.msalConfig = {
              auth: {
                clientId: this.clientid,
                authority: this.authority, //https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantid}
                navigateToLoginRequestUrl: true
              },
              cache: {
                cacheLocation: "sessionStorage",
                storeAuthStateInCookie: false,
              }
            };
            
    this.msalApp = new PublicClientApplication(this.msalConfig);
```

Comment: Hi did you check my answer? Is this issue resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `offline_access` in `scopes`:

```
scopes: ["openid", "profile", "offline_access", "User.Read"]
```